# Keras : Building a train function within for loop creates memory issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a double hidden layer CNN with policy gradient. I have a custom loss function for this. I am trying to implement it in Keras (backend TF) using the code for Cartpole game by kkweon. The code is as follows,

```
def _build_train_fn(network):
    action_prob_placeholder = network.output
    action_onehot_placeholder = K.placeholder(shape=(None, output_dim), 
                                              name = "action_onehot")
    discount_reward_placeholder = K.placeholder(shape=(None, ), 
                                                name = "discount_reward")

    action_prob = K.sum(action_prob_placeholder * action_onehot_placeholder, 
                        axis=1)
    log_action_prob = K.log(action_prob)

    loss = -log_action_prob * discount_reward_placeholder
    loss = K.mean(loss)

    adam = optimizers.Adam()

    updates = adam.get_updates(loss = loss, params = network.trainable_weights)

    train_fn = K.function(inputs=[network.input, 
                                       action_onehot_placeholder, 
                                       discount_reward_placeholder], 
                                outputs=[], updates=updates)
    return(train_fn)
```

Now I run the training function inside a for loop, where I take mini batches of episodes and train for that. So I need to build the train function for each mini batch, as it depends on the network output. The batch-wise training inside the for loop goes like this,

```
if episode_number % batch_size == 0:
            mini_batch_states = np.asarray(mini_batch_states).reshape([len(mini_batch_states), 14])
            mini_batch_moves = np.asarray(mini_batch_moves)

            train_fn = _build_train_fn(network)
            train_fn([mini_batch_states, mini_batch_moves, mini_batch_rewards])
```

The issue is that the memory usage continues to grow on size as the number of mini batches grow. I have tried building the function once before the loop, which solves the memory issue but removes the aspect of dynamic learning and converges to a 0.5 winrate instead of growing consistently.

Also using a

```
del train_fn
```

does not solve the memory issue.

I am very new to both TF and Keras. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I may be missing something, but how is your training function dependent on the network output? The function is just the set of operations done and that should be independent of what data the network currently took as input (and its related output). So yes, you should define the train function only once before the for loop (and investigate on what *other* reasons cause your network to converge to a suboptimum)

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to being one function call to train function, which solved the memory issue. The network is still converging to suboptimum though. The same code did not converge few days back. Don't know what is happening.